# Intuition for Lemma 4.3.1 in Shoenfield towards the Hilbert-Ackermann theorem

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, intuition

From Shoenfield's Mathematical Logic:

> The symbol consisting of the letter $c$ with the subscript $\exists
> xA$ is a *special constant* for $\exists xA$ (like the constants
> introduced to get a Henkin theory).
>
> The language obtained from $L$ by adding all the special constants is
> $L_c$. Let $T$ be a theory with the language $L$. Then $T_c$ is the
> theory whose language is $L_c$ and whose nonlogical axioms are the
> nonlogical axioms of $T$ and the special axioms for the special
> constants of $L_c$. The formula $\exists xA \to A_x[\mathbf{r}]$ is
> called the special axiom for $\mathbf{r}$.
>
> Let $\mathbf{r}$ be the special constant for $\exists x A$. A formula
> *belongs* to $\mathbf{r}$ if it is either the special axiom for $\mathbf{r}$ or a closed substitution axiom of the form
> $A_x[\mathbf{a}] \to \exists x A$. We designate by $\Delta(T)$ the set
> of formulas in $T_c$ which either belong to some special constant or
> are closed instances of identity axioms, equality axioms, or
> non-logical axioms of $T$.
>
> **Lemma 1.** If $\vdash_T A$, and $A'$ is a closed instance of $A$ in
> $L(T_c)$, then $A'$ is a tautological consequence of formulas in
> $\Delta(T)$.

This lemma is used in proving the Hilbert-Ackermann consistency theorem. What is the intuition behind the collection $\Delta(T)$ (what idea/concept does it signify)? How does the lemma progress towards the goal of the Hilbert-Ackermann theorem (how does it naturally arise as a question/problem)? I have a hard time grasping what we are trying to accomplish here. It feels a lot like pushing around formulas, and then voila there is the consistency theorem.

Comment: See **The Characterization Problem** (page 41): IMO, the gist of the Lemma is to find a way to "reduce" logical consequence to tautological consequence, that is (in principle) more manageable.

Comment: @Mauro I understand that, but what about $\Delta(T)$?